# Is the config object adapted to store datas from many users ( for the purpose of a subscription custom module )?

Tags: configuration

I have created a custom module that allows to subscribe to some news.

Each user ( and there will be thousands of them ) can register to some news category using that form

[image]

On form submit, the couple [loti, emails] is stored in a config object, as such:

```
 public function addSubscriberFromLot($lot, $userEmail) {
    $config = \Drupal::configFactory()
      ->getEditable('my_module_news_subscription.settings');
    $subscribersforLot = $config->get($lot);
    if ($subscribersforLot === null) {
      $config->set($lot, [$userEmail])->save();
    }
    elseif ($subscribersforLot !== null && !(in_array($userEmail, $subscribersforLot))) {
      array_push($subscribersforLot, $userEmail);
      $config->set($lot, $subscribersforLot)->save();
    }
  }
```

the config schema being

```
my_module_news_subscription.settings:
  type: mapping
  mapping:
    lot1:
      type: sequence
      label: ‘lot 1’
      sequence:
        type: string
        label: 'Email of subscribers'
    lot2:
      type: sequence
      label: ‘lot 2’
      sequence:
        type: string
        label: 'Email of subscribers'
    lot3:
      type: sequence
      label: ‘lot 3’
      sequence:
        type: string
        label: 'Email of subscribers'
    lot4:
      type: sequence
      label: ‘lot 4’
      sequence:
        type: string
        label: 'Email of subscribers'
    lot5:
      type: sequence
      label: ‘lot 5’
      sequence:
        type: string
        label: 'Email of subscribers'
```

Is there anything wrong with using that config object for that purpose ?

Can this withstand thousands of entries ?

Is there a more adapted way of store that datas ?

Answer (score 1):

Configuration defines your site. Users are not configuration, so neither would per-user settings be configuration.

If you need to save data per user, you can use the [user.data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.services.yml/service/user.data/9.4.x) service.

Comment: any exemple on how to use it ?

Comment: https://www.webomelette.com/storing-user-data-such-preferences-drupal-8-using-userdata-service